# Get class reference from top level function in kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin

I wrote a short program which does not require any classes and in turn consits of top level functions only.

To find your jar's location from java code you write

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()
```

But as I did not declare any classes in my kotlin code I don't know how to get a class reference.

My current implementation is this

```
class Ref
val jarPath = Ref::class.java.protectionDomain.codeSource.location.toURI().path
```

which is obviously very bad code.

So my question is, how do I obtain a class reference in kotlin without declaring any unneccesary classes.
Any hints appreciated :)

Comment: the code is not that bad ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can declare a class, but an anonymous one using the [object expression](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions), so that it won't be visible to the surrounding code:

```
val jarPath = object {}.javaClass.protectionDomain.codeSource.location.toURI().path
```